# inserting values in json file nested array elemnts

Tags: javascript, json, cordova

Iam trying to edit my json file using javascript.
My json file code is

```
{
"contacts": {
    "contact": {
        "info": [
            {
                "id": "0",
                "name": "name",
                "number": "0",
                "email": "email"
            }
        ],
        "messages": [
            {
                "message": [
                    {
                        "-from": "0",
                        "-to": "0",
                        "info": {
                            "id": "0",
                            "name": "name",
                            "number": "0",
                            "email": "email"
                        },
                        "text": [
                            {
                                "subText": {
                                    "-italics": "false",
                                    "-underline": "false"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "file": [
                            {
                                "-size": "0",
                                "-type": "image",
                                "fileInfo": {
                                    "id": "0",
                                    "name": "name",
                                    "number": "0",
                                    "email": "email"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
}
```

I want to set the value of contacts.contact.info.id   and i want to put another array in contacts.contact.info. plz help me with the syntax .
iam facing problem while creating while creating new element in info array.
and tell how to display values of the contacts.contact.info element

Comment: One thing the answerers haven't mentioned is that you need to ensure that you use `JSON.parse(json)` to get your data in a usable format before you update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

```
var json={contacts:{contact:{info:[{id:"0",name:"name",number:"0",email:"email"}],messages:[{message:[{"-from":"0","-to":"0",info:{id:"0",name:"name",number:"0",email:"email"},text:[{subText:{"-italics":"false","-underline":"false"}}],file:[{"-size":"0","-type":"image",fileInfo:{id:"0",name:"name",number:"0",email:"email"}}]}]}]}}};

console.log(json.contacts.contact.info[0]); //access first record

json.contacts.contact.info.push({id:"1",name:"name",number:"1",email:"abc@xyz.com"}); // add new info

console.log(json.contacts.contact.info);
```

Comment: hi arvind what to do in case of array in a array, if i have to update contacts.messages.message.info.id .

Comment: @Leftalone you may use `json.contacts.contact.messages[0].message[0].info.id`='new value'

Comment: the json.contacts.contact.info.push({data}; method is working only once. if i have two elements in the info array the push thing is not working.

Answer (score 2):

Using JavaScript, it's perfectly simple:

```
var data = {};//your json string here
data.contacts.contact.info[0].id = 'New value here'; //id is in array
data.contacts.contact.info.push('Append this value to info');
//or
data.contacts.contact.info = 'Overwrite current info value';
//get string
console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```

That's all. If you want to manually alter the data:

```
{
"contacts": {
    "contact": {
        "info": [
            {
                "id": "0",//replace with, for example:
                "name": "name",
                "number": "0",
                "email": "email"
            },//add comma, and data below:
            {
                "id": "123",
                "name": "foobar",
                "number": "1"
            },
            "primitives go here, too"
        ],//end array
        "messages": [...
```

That's all there is to it.
To preserve the pretty-printing, as you requested:

```
var data = JSON.parse(yourString);
data.contacts.contact.info.push(
    {"id": "7","name": "dg","number": "5454","email": "fsfsf"}
);
data.contacts.contact.info.push(
    {"id": "8","name": "gjhhk","number": "64564","email": "fs54f"}
);
//get pretty string, using spaces for indentation:
console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, ' '));
//same thing, but using tabs:
console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, '\t'));
```

Comment: i have stored my json data in file and im fetching it and parsing it using json.parse(); and inserting data using data.contacts.contact.info = 'Overwrite current info value'; but when i use data.contacts.contact.info.push('Append this value to info');  , its not working.

Comment: @Leftalone: if you do that, then `data.contacts.contact.info` won't be an array anymore. If you want to _add_ data, use the `push` method on the array. To replace, consider assigning a new array, to ensure data structure consistency

Comment: if i have a array inside a array, how to fetch it.

Comment: @Leftalone: that's pretty basic: suppose `var matrix = [[1,2],[3,4]];` just use 2 indexes: `console.log((matrix[0][0] + matrix[0][1]) === matrix[1][0]);` will log `true`, because 1 + 2 === 3

Comment: the json.contacts.contact.info.push({data}; method is working only once. if i have two elements in the info array the push thing is not working.

Comment: @Leftalone: is `info` still an array after you `push` something? What are you pushing, because your snippet `info.push({data})` looks invalid to me: `{}` is an object literal, but there is no key-value pair. It should be `info.push({data: data})`

Comment: contacts.contact.info.push({"id": "7","name": "dg","number": "5454","email": "fsfsf"});   this is succeessful once but after when i contacts.contact.info.push({"id": "8","name": "gjhhk","number": "64564","email": "fs54f"});. the first value is been added in the json file but second is not being inserted.

Comment: @Leftalone: Set up a jsfiddle, with some more code, because I can't really tell what the issue is from 2 statements without any context...

Comment: got the real problem. I have stored json data in a file which is properly intended. Im reading the file and parsing it using var jj = JSON.parse(jsonString);   and after successful edit im applying var myname=JSON.stringify(jj); .   now after stringify(); function the data updated in file is in single line with no spaces and proper indentation. can i preserve whitespaces and new line characters.

Comment: @leftalone: Yes, you can [check the manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify): `JSON.stringify(jj, null, ' ');` or `JSON.stringify(jj, null, '\t')`, depending on your needs

Answer (score 0):

for **contacts.contact.info.id** :

contacts.contact.info is an array.. so you have to work by index like:

```
contacts.contact.info[0].id = newID;
```

to Add to this array:

```
contacts.contact.info.push(newArrayItem);
```

hope this answers your questions..